# Upload file to SharePoint using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I'm using client-side object model (CSOM) for file upload in my Powershell script. Every time i run it a new version has been created after metadata has been set.

[image: Document History]

How can I fix this, so only one version will be created?

Code:

```
#Upload to SharePoint
$FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
$FileCreationInfo.URL = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $FolderName + "/" + $SourceFileName 
$FileUploaded = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)

#Set Metadata
$properties = $FileUploaded.ListItemAllFields;
$Context.Load($properties)
$properties["DocLanguage"]="EN"
$properties.Update()

$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running against SharePoint Online the latest CSOM nuget package has the SystemUpdate() method in it. Using that should not create any new versions or update the Modified/Modified By fields. If you're on-prem I don't think there is a way short of deleting the latest version after updating the metadata.